# printf showing error while compiling

Tags: c, codeblocks

I'm new to C programming and I just came across this program and got a problem. It says it has error on the line I indicated. Can any one help?

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <conio.h>
int main()
{
    float a;
    printf("Hello world!\n");
    scanf("%d",&a)
    printf("you entered: %f",a);//here is the error
    getch()

}
```

I'm using CodeBlocks.

Comment: Just one comment: `conio.h` is not part of the standard C library. Neither is `getch()`: http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Conio.h You might want to consider not using these EVER :)

Comment: Next time, please post the actual error message you get.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I see two semi-colons missing...

The scanf line needs one also to advise the compiler that the instruction is ending, and you're likely seeing the error on the next line because it thinks it's on the previous line still.

Answer (score 3):

Missing semi-colon after `getch()`? and after `scanf()`?

Comment: @NishchalGautam whenever you get an error at a particular line, search for errors in and around that line too

Answer (score 1):

You are missing a semicolon at the end of

```
scanf("%d",&a)
```

and

```
getch()
```

Answer (score 0):

Several missing semicolons:

```
float a;
printf("Hello world!\n");
scanf("%d",&a); <--- HERE
printf("you entered: %f",a);//here is the error
getch(); <--- AND HERE
```

Comment: It should be `%f` (or equivalent) for float in `scanf`